# Laravel project too large

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, gitignore, laravel-storage

I tried pushing my project with git to a remote repo, I noticed the compressing and writing of files is taking too long! I checked project size and it is 460MB +.

I check vendor folder it just ~25MB, app folder and all the other major folders are having normal sizes and the project is supposed to weight about 60MB (and a git push should upload like 25MB since the vendor folder is ignored) I check storage folder and it weights more than 400MB!!! I don't know how that happened! What's surprising is that even if I actually uploaded files to that folder it is not supposed to upload according to the .gitignore file! And I haven't performed any uploads to the storage dir!

However I see some funny files inside /storage/boot. I have included a screen shot one those files averagely weight 30MB.

The problem is very strange and I don't know how to go about it. That is my gitignore file I added the /storage for benefits of doubt since I know its same as /public/storage nothing changed!!! Need help thanks in advance.

```
/vendor
/node_modules
/public/storage
/storage
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
.env
```

[image]

Comment: `git rm --cache /storage` then commit again

Comment: I think adding `/storage` to `.gitignore` is not enough if they are already being tracked. You need to do `git rm -r storage` and then commit and push.

Comment: May be, You are storing files in public folder and no delete for long time ?

Comment: you might even want to read this: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/ This way you can remove your vendor folder etc. from the entire history

Comment: Wow that's a linux boot directory in there. That's funky to have in your stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the files inside storage/logs to decrease the size. Its just the logs created by Laravel in case of errors